# Can't get CSS and JS files to load on Cordova Android Production Release

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-permissions

I have a Cordova App which works fine when I run and test it locally but when I build, sign, and deploy to production in the Google Play Console, the externally loaded JS and CSS does not load.

CSS file not loading:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/application.min.20171213v2.css">
```

JS files not loading:

```
<script src="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/thirdparties.min.20171213v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://app.winetracker.co/dist/application.min.20171213v2.js"></script>
```

[image]

Excerpt from my config.xml file:

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.winetracker.co/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
```

Is there some other config.xml setting I should try or AndroidManifest.xml config? Any advice is much appreciated. I'm stumped!

Comment: Using Cordova 8.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue of having configuration of my SSL cert not being fully configured. Once I complied with all the SSL settings properly the issue was resolved with my app.

Android was choking on my partially configured SSL keys. You can check your web app / cordova app by pulling up the app url here:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=[YOUR WEB APP URL HERE]